# Laravel 5.2 Validator Throuing exception instead of redirecting back when debug mode is off

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I upgraded my site to Laravel 5.2 and now if I user don't enter any value in fields instead of redirecting it back to previous and flash error message it show exceptions. Below is my sample code.

```
public function save(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'slug' => 'required'
    ]);

}
```

I tried adding below lines in `App\Exceptions\Handler` class but still not working.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler {
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        AuthorizationException::class,
        HttpException::class,
        ModelNotFoundException::class,
        ValidationException::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $e) {
        return parent::report($e);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $e) {

        if (!config('app.debug') && !$this->isHttpException($e)) {

                return redirect('404');
        }

        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your full app/Exceptions/Handler.php

Comment: @MattMcDonald full file included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you're not catching HttpResponseExceptions in your render method.

Try this:

```
namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Http\Exception\HttpResponseException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler {
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        AuthorizationException::class,
        HttpException::class,
        ModelNotFoundException::class,
        ValidationException::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $e) {
        return parent::report($e);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $e) {

        if (!config('app.debug') && !$this->isHttpException($e) && !$e instanceof HttpResponseException) {

                return redirect('404');
        }

        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is still redirecting to 404 page.

Comment: Did you remember `use Illuminate\Http\Exception\HttpResponseException;`